# Android emulator - error

Tags: android, android-emulator, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to run my sample sencha app 2 on android emulator, but it gives me the below error.

```
C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp>sencha app build native
[INFO] Deploying your application to C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\build\package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[INFO] Found 139 dependencies. Concatenating all into app.js...
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
[INFO] ""C:Program FilesAndroidandroid-sdk/tools/android" create project --targe
t android-7 --name MyApplication --activity STActivity --path "C:\path\to\www\my
senchaapp\build\native/" --package com.mycompany.myAppID"
Failed to create android project
Failed to package application
[ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Please let me know , what is the issue here.

Thanks for your time and support

**Updated;**

```
C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp>sencha app build native
[INFO] Deploying your application to C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\build\package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[INFO] Found 139 dependencies. Concatenating all into app.js...
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
[INFO] ""C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/tools/android" create project --
rget android-7 --name MyApplication --activity STActivity --path "C:\path\to\w
\mysenchaapp\build\native/" --package com.mycompany.myAppID"
Failed to copy packager library
Failed to package application
[ERROR] Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android.bat list targets' to get t
 target ids.
Copy operation failed src=C:/Windows/stbuild/st-res/android//nimblekit.jar dst
:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\build\native//libs/nimblekit.jar
```

Comment: Broken path? "C:Program FilesAndroidandroid-sdk/tools/android"

Comment: @AlexFlorescu: hi, broken path you mean? how can i fix it

Comment: That path (which is the path to your android sdk) is obviously incorrect. You need to fix the PATH environment variable and/or in ADT, depending on what you're using to build this now. See: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing and http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents

Comment: @AlexFlorescu: i have fixed the path inside the packager.xml. now i have the above mentioned error. pls check my updated question

Comment: First link on Google for that error: http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=96